# What are the named ports for iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

When setting up iptables you can name the port ssh which will use port 22. Is there a list of all the named ports? Specifically I need ssh, http, https and mysql.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

On your installation, the list will be based on the file /etc/services

Comment: Thanks this definately makes iptables more readable to other admins.

Answer (score 6):

The list of "Well-Known Ports" is maintained by the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA).  The latest version can be found at http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers.

Note that most Linux distributions include a subset of the list in `/etc/services` for use in referring to them symbolically.  Windows has it in `%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\services`.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is not governed, though, and it's not an exhaustive list of what you might find. A developer can pick whatever port they want for the app to talk on. Doesn't mean it's smart, but they can do it...

Answer (score 0):

ssh tcp/22
http tcp/80
https tcp/443
mysql clustering tcp/1186 and udp/1186
mysql tcp/3306